# Convergence Criteria in glmmTMB - what are my options?

Tags: r, convergence, glmmtmb

When using `glmmTMB()` of the R-package [`{glmmTMB}`](https://glmmtmb.github.io/glmmTMB/) (see [CRAN with links to manual & vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/index.html)), I am aware that I have certain options when dealing with the convergence of models. More specifically, there is the `control =` argument to which I can pass `glmmTMBControl()` parameters, whose section in the manual is this:

[image]

Furthermore, one of the vignettes - i.e. [Troubleshooting with glmmTMB](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html) - talks explicitly about dealing with convergence problems. My key point is now, however, that to my knowledge any time `glmmTMBControl()` is mentioned, it is always in one of these two ways:

- `glmmTMBControl(optCtrl=list(iter.max=1e3,eval.max=1e3))` i.e. increase the number of iterations
- `glmmTMBControl(optimizer=optim, optArgs=list(method="BFGS"))` i.e. try a different optimizer

Regarding the second one, I am left with the impression that I have multiple options besides the one shown there since "The optimizer argument can be any optimization (minimizing) function [...]" and the following phrasing:

[image]

Yet, I was not able to find out about any other options I could actually put as my `optimizer=`, since it really seems to be the exact example shown above that is presented, and I would be thankful if someone could provide a list.

P.S.: I am trying to play around with `glmmTMB`s convergence criteria, because it seems to often estimate slightly smaller variance components compared to the same model fit via `PROC MIXED` in SAS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?glmmTMB`:

> The ‘optimizer’ argument can be any optimization (minimizing) function, provided that:
> • the first three arguments, in order, are the starting values, objective function, and gradient function;
> • the function also takes a ‘control’ argument;
> • the function returns a list with elements (at least) ‘par’,
> ‘objective’, ‘convergence’ (0 if convergence is successful)
> and ‘message’ (‘glmmTMB’ automatically handles output from
> ‘optim()’, by renaming the ‘value’ component to ‘objective’)

The options built into base R that satisfy these requirements (gradient-based minimizers) are `nlminb` and `optim` with `method="BFGS"`, `"L-BFGS-B"`, or `"CG"`. You could also look into optimizers provided by `optimx` or `nloptr`, but you'd probably have to write a wrapper function to make sure they satisfied the criteria above ...